# Create new project with fpcomplete

Tags: haskell

When I try to create a new haskell project using https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/new-project I receive page not found exception. Is this the correct url for creating a new project with fpcomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FP Complete's Haskell Center is no longer available: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/10/retiring-fphc

Comment: thanks, so no longer can create projects via Haskell online ide ? advises to use 'The Haskell Tool Stack' which is OS (non browser) based.

Comment: No, you can't create projects (or work with existing projects).